# What was the inspiration for Burnham's speech from the end of the Klingon war, in Star Trek Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In the Discover Season 1 finale, [Will You Take My Hand](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Will_You_Take_My_Hand%3F_(episode)), Michael Burnham delivers a speech, the beginning of which is used as a voiceover during the prologue of the episode and the remainder begins the epilogue, revealing that the speech is being given at a ceremony to mark the end of the war.

> On the eve of battle, on a cold and windless night, an old general turned to a young soldier. "Tomorrow," said the master, "you will know fear." The young soldier, who had not yet experienced the agony of war, looked at the general with quizzical eyes. "How will I know fear if I do not know what it looks like?" The general replied, "You will know fear because it speaks very fast and it speaks very loud."
> If that is how fear acts, recognizing it is easy. But as the young soldier considered the general's advice, she asked the question facing us now: "Once I know fear, how do I defeat it?" We are no longer on the eve of battle. Even so, I come to ask myself the same question that young soldier asked the general all those years ago: "How do I defeat fear?" The general's answer: "The only way to defeat fear is to tell it 'no.'" No. We will not take shortcuts on the path to righteousness. No. We will not break the rules that protect us from our basest instincts. No. We will not allow desperation to destroy moral authority. I am guilty of all these things. Some say that in life, there are no second chances. Experience tells me that this is true. But we can only look forward. We have to be torchbearers, casting the light so we may see our path to lasting peace. We will continue exploring, discovering new worlds, new civilizations. Yes. That is the United Federation of Planets. Yes. That is Starfleet. Yes. That is who we are. And who we will always be.

Is this speech based on a real world incident? An in-universe incident? A work of fiction? Or was it entirely made up for the episode?

And, if it was made up, are the core quotes from it, *"You will know fear because it speaks very loud and very fast,"* and, *"The only way to defeat fear is to tell it 'no',"* taken from somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have some reason to suspect that it wasn't just made up for the show? That might be helpful.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - The manner in which Burnham relays the tale as an example of imparted wisdom makes it seem like it should be taken as a historical reference.

Comment: Much of the second half of that speech sounded to me a lot like "We thought this was going to feel like Star Trek, but we're going to try even harder next season, promise!"